# JBOSS Deployment interception

Tags: jboss, interception

I would like to execute a code once an application gets deployed completely on JBOSS, is there a way to intercept application deployment on JBOSS, or is there a point where I can be very sure that the application has been deployed completely and I can execute my code just after that point.

Comment: i am also interested in this question. Maybe @James R. Perkins knows something more about this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using special auto start servlet to initialize on startup and share application data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468150/using-special-auto-start-servlet-to-initialize-on-startup-and-share-application)

Answer (score 0):

Reading [Execute code after Glassfish Web Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603521/execute-code-after-glassfish-web-deployment) i came to the answer of this question.

We have the ability to code a ServletContextListener to be triggered when the context is loaded like this:

```
public class MyServlet implements ServletContextListener {

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
         // implementation code
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {
         // implementation code
  }
}
```

Reference:

- [Example of ServletContextListener](http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/servletcontextlistener-example/)

Thanks to Garis Suero